# undefined reference to `boost::re_detail

Tags: boost, compilation

I am catkin_make VINS-MONO,and the error:

```
undefined reference to `boost::re_detail`
undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::directory_iterator
```

comes out,why?

When I compiling the VINS-MONO,catkin_make:
here is the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /home/long/cv_bridge_ws/devel/lib/libcv_bridge.so: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_107300::perl_matcher<char const*, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<char const*> >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::construct_init(boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/long/cv_bridge_ws/devel/lib/libcv_bridge.so: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_107300::perl_matcher<char const*, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<char const*> >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::match()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [VINS-Mono/ar_demo/CMakeFiles/ar_demo_node.dir/build.make:198: /home/long/catkin_vs/devel/lib/ar_demo/ar_demo_node] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1779: VINS-Mono/ar_demo/CMakeFiles/ar_demo_node.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: No space left on device
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [VINS-Mono/pose_graph/CMakeFiles/pose_graph.dir/build.make:387: /home/long/catkin_vs/devel/lib/pose_graph/pose_graph] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1961: VINS-Mono/pose_graph/CMakeFiles/pose_graph.dir/all] Error 2
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: No space left on device
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [VINS-Mono/feature_tracker/CMakeFiles/feature_tracker.dir/build.make:220: /home/long/catkin_vs/devel/lib/feature_tracker/feature_tracker] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1805: VINS-Mono/feature_tracker/CMakeFiles/feature_tracker.dir/all] Error 2
[ 55%] Linking CXX executable /home/long/catkin_vs/devel/lib/camera_model/Calibration
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Calibration.dir/src/intrinsic_calib.cc.o: in function `main':
intrinsic_calib.cc:(.text.startup+0x121a): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::directory_iterator_construct(boost::filesystem::directory_iterator&, boost::filesystem::path const&, unsigned int, boost::system::error_code*)'
/usr/bin/ld: intrinsic_calib.cc:(.text.startup+0x125b): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::directory_entry::get_status(boost::system::error_code*) const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [VINS-Mono/camera_model/CMakeFiles/Calibration.dir/build.make:340: /home/long/catkin_vs/devel/lib/camera_model/Calibration] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1727: VINS-Mono/camera_model/CMakeFiles/Calibration.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j8 -l8" failed
```

Comment: Is there problem about BOOST?Because I made a mistake to delete some files about boost,and I have re-install the boost.But I encounter this problem when I compiled.

Comment: Can you tell us the steps you take to compile, what platform, versions etc? Most likely it's just a missing linker input but we cannot tell. It's not even clear whether this is about your code or an open source library etc.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are running out of disk space:

> /usr/bin/ld: final link failed: No space left on device

Try to make space or move the build location to a volume that has more free space available.